# 'swimming dog' and 'dog swimming'?

Tags: grammar

1. I saw a swimming dog.
2. I saw a dog swimming.

What is the difference between the two sentences in meaning.
And is there any reason why we should change the order of the word( dog, swimming)?

Comment: I have added indefinite articles to your examples to improve them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you saw was a dog in water swimming, and were mentioning that, it would be correct to say ***a dog swimming***; *swimming* being a present participle, indicating what the dog was doing. *The dog was swimming*

However if the *...ing* form of verb is placed before the noun, *swimming* becomes an adjective qualifying the noun *dog*. Grammatically it could be one of two things:

a) The ***swimming dog*** could have been a certain type of dog which swims a lot. *I saw a swimming dog* does not necessarily mean the dog was swimming when you saw it. It was just a type of dog which swims (notwithstanding the fact that most dogs can swim)

b) It could mean the same thing as ***a dog swimming***. But it would be an unusual way of expressing it. The normal idiomatic form would be ***a dog swimming***.

Comment: A good example of this might be "I saw the running celebrity Mo Farah at the BBC in London" and , "I saw the celebrity Mo Farah running at the London Olympics". Mr Farah would almost certainly be sitting and walking at the BBC but, as he is known as a runner, he is a running celebrity whatever he is doing. However when competing in a race he would be actually running.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example-

1.**I saw a lying man today.**

2.**I saw a man lying today.**

In the first example lying is **adjective**.

In the second example lying is **verb**.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: They're verbs in both examples.